# Maven: How to pass command-line arguments from release:perform to deploy?

Tags: maven, maven-release-plugin

When I invoke `release:peform` on my project. it invokes `deploy` which in-turn invokes `gpg`. I'd like to pass the gpg passphrase into the process using a system property or environment variable but neither seems to work.

If I invoke `mvn.bat '-Darguments="-Dgpg_passphrase=test"' -Pwindows-i386-msvc-debug -DconnectionUrl=scm:hg:https://boost-maven-project.googlecode.com/hg/ release:perform` Maven ends up invoking:

`cmd.exe /X /C mvn deploy --no-plugin-updates -Psonatype-oss-release -P windows-i386-msvc-debug,always-active -f pom.xml"`

And as you can see, neither environment variables nor the `-Darguments` command-line arguments are passed to the `deploy` goal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this is caused by a Sonatype bug: https://issues.sonatype.org/browse/CENTRALSRV-35

Answer (score 0):

You have configured as `-Denv.gpg_passphrase=test`, Please correct me, if I'm wrong. I understand that you are trying to pass the environment variable which is not allowed here. it is a system properties named `env.gpg_passphrase` instead. The `-D` is always the system properties.

If you would like to use the environment variable, please configure through the OS configuration instead. If you would like to use the system properties please use -D. Please do not mix these two types.

IMHO, I've a scenario as your mentioning to sign the artifact as well. I configure by specifying the "[maven-release-plugin](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html)" explicitly at the build section as the following example.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${my.maven.release.version}</version>
            <configuration>
                <arguments>${my.release.arguments}</arguments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    <plugins>
</build>
```

I also configure the properties named *my.release.arguments* at each developer *settings.xml* for security purpose (do not share the secret, e.g. user/password/private key,etc.). I am able like to know and identify who releases these artifacts by looking at the signature.

I hope this may help.

Regards,

Charlee Ch.